# FInd a graph on a vertex set similar to another graph

Tags: graphs

I am looking for a possible algorithmic solution to this problem, but I can't figure out any.

Let's say I have a weighted graph (call it G); each vertex on this graph represents a point in a plane, and each edge has the distance as its weight.

Now I have another set of vertex, let's call it S, representing points in the same plane.

My goal is to find a new graph whose vertex are taken from S, and that should be "as similar as possible" to the graph G. For me similar means that reciprocal positions and distances for connected vertices must be similar as much as possible to those of correspondent vertices in G.

Maybe such an algorithm already exists but I did not manage to find it.

Thank you for your time!

**Edit:** there is no correspondences between vertices as an input of the problem. I'll try to better explain the metric of similarity; since vertices may represent geographical coordinates I would like this two properties:

- Correspondent edges weight (i.e distance of connected vertices) should be as close as possible.
- Correspondent edges direction (i.e. variation of connected vertices coordinates on each axis) should be as close as possible.

This kind of "reciprocal position" constraint is needed because vertices represent geographical points. Also, not every point in *S* has to be chosen as a vertex for the new graph since it may contains more points than the number of vertices of *G*.

Thanks

Comment: What is meant by "reciprocal positions"?  When you mention "correspondent vertices", are we given a correspondence between vertices of $G$ and points of $S$ as part of the input to the algorithm?  What does "similar as much as possible" mean?  What specific measure of similarity do you have in mind?  Can you identify a specific objective function that you want to minimize?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have correspondences between vertex as an input. Imagine that each vertex is a geographical position. "reciprocal position" means that distances should be preserved. My measure of similarity should cab be this:
- The graphs are similar if two correspondent edges weight difference approaches to zero
- The graphs are similar if two correspondent edges direction (expressed in vertex coordinates variation) difference approaches to zero

Maybe I can find an objective function based on this metrics.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to incorporate those clarifications?  We want questions to stand on their own, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  I still don't see a clear definition of an objective function to minimize.  "approaches to zero" is vague; there might be a tradeoff (e.g., I can get the distance AB closer to accurate but at the cost of getting the distance BC less accurate; is that better or worse?  how would I tell)